Typescript syntax highlighting uses Error for keywords
I'm having trouble getting good syntax highlighting for typescript files. The issue is that reserved words are highlighted as Error:

Looking at :scriptnames I see the default typescript highlighting being sourced, and later leafgarland/typescript-vim being sourced. I'd expect the second to override the first, but looking at both sources, the Error highlighting comes from the default typescript highlighting (why?), whereas typescript-vim highlights keywords as Keyword.
How can I fix things so my typescript keywords don't look like errors?
Software and version details:

WSL running Ubuntu 22.04 under windows 11
VIM 8.2
typescript-vim at latest available commit (8d169e16b)


I tried upgrading vim to 9.0 since I realized 8.2 is quite old, but it has the same issue.

Removing typescript-vim seems to have fixed the issue! Still curious where it is coming from.

NOTE: This Typescript syntax was created before Typescript's 1.0 release, more than a decade ago. - I wonder if that's anything to do with it...

Probably... it's weird though, it works without issues in Cygwin and on macos.

In that case, it might be another case of Debian's packaging policy. You have to apt-get install vim-gtk3 to get the full version with all runtime files. The default (I think) vim-tiny leads to surprises. Just another blind guess.

That's a good guess, that did cause issues for me earlier, but I'm currently using vim-athena which I think is very similar.
